# How to make a small change with a meaningful commit message that can be reverted?

Tags: git

In using Git, I try to make one small change at a time and commit each change separately. This lets me have detailed commit messages, and lets me revert individual changes easily, as described in this [blog post](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/git-your-act-together/) (not mine). Sometimes when working on one large feature, I will see a small unrelated bug that I would like to fix. As per my current system, I have to note the bug to fix later (usually as a code comment), commit the large feature, then go back and fix the bug.

I am wondering if branches will let me make fix the bug and push the commit immediately, while I finish the feature in another branch. Can I push the fix to both the public repository *and* to my 'adding feature' branch? Branches seem a bit unwieldy for this, is there a simpler method to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: stash your current large changes, fix the small bug and push, then stash pop?

Comment: @Billiska that'd be the answer

Comment: Thank you, I had not yet heard of [Git Stashing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing)

Comment: Either stashing (as Billiska says) or branching (as Klaus says) is appropriate, according to how big the change is. I tend to find stashes a little more opaque than branches so I avoid making large changes with them. Definitely take the time to become skilled with both.

Comment: @kampu: Will do! Thank you, this has been a very productive question for me (two terrific answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should be developing your feature in a feature branch (see, for instance, [this branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)).

So you do your feature work in your feature branch. When a bug fix is needed, you

1. Switch from the feature branch to your master branch
2. Do the bug fix in master
3. Push master
4. Switch back to your feature branch
5. Continue work on the feature

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I might be after. But how to perform step `3.5 push bug fix to feature branch`? I could just diff and patch, but is there a better way?

Comment: @dotancohen: you probably want `git merge` (`git merge SOMEBRANCH` will bring the current branch uptodate with any changes in SOMEBRANCH)

Comment: @dotancohen `git merge` works. Alternatively, if you have not pushed your feature branch, you could `git rebase` the feature branch on your master branch (`git rebase master` when on the feature branch).

Answer (score 1):

You ask if branching is a *solution* to your problem, so I won't assume you are already on a branch like other answers.

It's very easy to address your problem in a single branch.  It's why `git` distinguishes the working copy from changes staged to be committed.  In your case, fix the bug and use `git add -p` to add only the patchset you care about.  You can use `git add <file>` if you don't have any other work in the same file.  Then `git commit` (note, **not** `git commit -a`, which implies adding everything) that one patch and resume your feature work.

I frequently use this for the reason you describe, and then for the final feature checkin I used it again to split the major feature into smaller atomic checkins (if applicable).

Comment: Thank you Ben. This is a good idea for smaller single changes.